# Enabling Content Delivery API for a single site in a multi site setup

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I have a multisite environment. I have installed Content Delivery API & that works as expected. However, is there a configuration setting related to content delivery api that will allow access to a single site?
The CMS version that I am on is 11.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out "Multi-site filtering" in the docs

https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/developer-guides/archive/content-delivery-api/installing/installing/

Comment: Thanks Eric for the response.I did check this option but this is specific to filtering the content response api.What I am looking for is since I have multiple sites hosted ,I want content delivery API to be enabled for a single site.

Comment: @FarhinShaikh that's what the docs say. Write your queries to the site where you wish to get responses from. E.g www.mysite.com/api/... that won't return pages from www.mysite2.com if you have the multi-site filtering enabled. The content delivery API will not restrict the access to other sites, but you can implement a `ContentModelMapperBase` and block requests that way using the `TransformContent` having it throwing an error or just return a blank result.

Comment: @FarhinShaikh An additional option might be to manage this using site access, e.g. the user you use when accessing the content delivery might have access to only a certain website in the CMS.

Comment: Thanks for the input @EricHerlitz .I created a site level bool property to enable content delivery api & created a CustomContentModelMapperBase overwriting TransformContent  to return the content if enabled else return null.